# Developing An "Add To Favourites" Button In PHP

Tags: php, html, e-commerce, shopping-cart, cart

I'm creating a small website using PHP which is generally a site for showcasing the products of a certain shop. The site has the functions where a user can create his/her account, log in and then he/she should be able to favor add any product they like to their own wish list. Then the favored products should be displayed when they view their wish list (that can be managed).

I'm looking for a way where if a user click on the favourite button on a product, then the product should be favored without the page getting reloaded. I know we should use AJAX but how?

The websites I've given below have that feature I'm trying to explain (but they require to sign up though).

[example one](https://www.etsy.com/)

[example two](http://www.ikman.lk)

Note: Sorry if this is a very dumb question, I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: Something along these lines should help you out a bit. [Building a 5 Star Rating System with jQuery, AJAX and PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php/)

Comment: user555 thanks alot il check it out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a simple script in php to add the item to the favorites, while doing that make the assumption that the item id will be passed with the $_REQUEST.  This should be a short script that only adds the item to the favoritese and return a success or error, typically in json.  Json can be encoded in php using `json_encode()` and can be decoded in js using `JSON.parse()`.

This tidbit helped when I first started with Ajax.  Ajax is just using js or jQuery from within the browser to open php pages without the actual webpage loading.  This  is super helpful because you can communicate data to and from the server without reloading the webpage.

Comment: I would rather use `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: i understand what you say and I exactly do what you have said above by storing the items primary key and the users key in a separate table and the product is stored successfully, but for the whole process to happen the page should get reloaded. So in order to fix that i should work with AJAX and JSON according to your answer, but I'm completely null in that, I will be touching up on the from now on, thanks alot for your answer and let me know if there are any codes or any tuts to guide me through.... thanks :) @rymn

Comment: Well, with no experience, I would start here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/build-an-ajax-powered-shopping-cart/GL!!

Answer (score 0):

Ajax in easy steps:
0. Add ajax code
You can use mini ajax from Google:

Javascript:

```
function $(e){if(typeof e=='string')e=document.getElementById(e);return e};
function collect(a,f){var n=[];for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){var v=f(a[i]);
if(v!=null)n.push(v)}return n};
ajax={};
ajax.x=function(){try{return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')}catch(e)
{try{return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')}catch(e)
{return new XMLHttpRequest()}}};
ajax.serialize=function(f){var g=function(n){return f.getElementsByTagName(n)};
var nv=function(e){if(e.name)return encodeURIComponent(e.name)
+'='+encodeURIComponent(e.value);else return ''};var i=collect(g('input'),function(i){if((i.type!='radio'&&i.type!='checkbox')||i.checked)return nv(i)});var s=collect(g('select'),nv);var t=collect(g('textarea'),nv);return i.concat(s).concat(t).join('&');};
ajax.send=function(u,f,m,a){var x=ajax.x();x.open(m,u,true);x.onreadystatechange=function(){if(x.readyState==4)f(x.responseText)};if(m=='POST')x.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');x.send(a)};
ajax.get=function(url,func){ajax.send(url,func,'GET')};
ajax.gets=function(url){var x=ajax.x();x.open('GET',url,false);x.send(null);return x.responseText};
ajax.post=function(url,func,args){ajax.send(url,func,'POST',args)};
ajax.update=function(url,elm){var e=$(elm);var f=function(r){e.innerHTML=r};ajax.get(url,f)};
ajax.submit=function(url,elm,frm){var e=$(elm);var f=function(r){e.innerHTML=r};ajax.post(url,f,ajax.serialize(frm))};
```

1. Create page element which uses ajax to replace own content
   Use mini ajax in HTML to replace content of ProdFav element with content generated by ajax.php (described below):
   `<div id="ProdFav">
      <a href="#fav" onclick="ajax.update(urlROOT + 'ajax.php?action=ProdFavs&prod_id=' + prod_id + '&state=on', 'ProdFav'); return false;"><span class="dis">Make favorite</span></a>
      </div>`
2. Create php to serve new content
   ajax.php uses action and prod_id parameters to create new content for ProdFav html element:

PHP:

```
echo '
<a href="#fav"
  onclick="ajax.update(urlROOT + \'ajax.php?action=ProdFavs&prod_id=\' + '
   .intval($_GET['prod_id'])
   .' + \'&state=off\', \'ProdFav\'); return false;">
       <span class="dis">Remove favorite</span>
</a>';
```